# How to create a link to user/role login page of Peter's Login Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication, login-control

I'm using Peter's Login Redirect in Wordpress to redirect each User/Role to its "Personal Page".

It's all working great, but I would like to create a link where any user could click and be redirected back to its Login Redirect's page.

Right now, when a user login it goes to their "Personal Page", but when clicked into another link, there is no way to come back to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve it I add some code into the functions.php to make able to run PHP code inside widgets.

This is the code that I add into functions.php

```
add_filter('widget_text','execute_php',100);
function execute_php($html){
     if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){
          ob_start();
          eval("?".">".$html);
          $html=ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
     }
     return $html;
}
```

After this I just add the HTML/PHP code to create a link that would redirect the current user to its personal page. I placed this code inside the text the should be presented when the user is logged in of the login widget plugin that I'm using.

```
<a href="<?php echo redirect_to_front_page( false, false, wp_get_current_user()); ?>">Your Page</a>
```

So That's it. If necessary more explanation about what I've done, please leave a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [`redirect_to_front_page($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user)`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/peters-login-redirect/trunk/wplogin_redirect.php#L474) that is part of the plugin. It is primarily used as part of the [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) filter, so you can see more info about the arguments there. To use outside of this filter you could do something like the following, passing in `false` for the redirect URLS and detect if it is updated via your rules.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user =  get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
if ( false !== ( $redirect_url = redirect_to_front_page( false, false, $user ) ) ){
    // $redirect_url is the custom URL
} else {
    // there is no custom URL
}
```

Comment: So inside the true statement I'll have to call something the redirects into `$redirect_url` ? And in the false/else statement I'll have to call it to a default page correct ?

Where should I place this code? Inside theme files editor ? I was thinking about place this link inside the login widget, but I don't believe it allows me to add PHP code inside it. Sorry I'm perry new into WP, I had never got deeper in it.

Comment: I used the steps described in this [link](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/04/11/executing-php-inside-a-wordpress-widget-without-any-plugin/) where it makes the `text widget` able to tun php code, than I inserted the code just as you code making a `echo "ok";` when true and `echo "fail"` when false. But it didn't work. When using just simple PHP code as a `echo "Hello World"` it works. I did try to print the `$user` var, but didn't work. As it's protected by WP configuration, I don't get any error message from php.

Comment: I was missing a parenthesis so you were probably getting a syntax error, but the code above is meant to be an example so you will need to debug on your server to be sure it's working. Feel free to try the above code again, it might work now that the syntax is correct.

Comment: I posted an answer using some ideias from you answer in it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question you asked, you just solved another issue.